# 'Update existing item' in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, solution-explorer

I have a set of fonts inside my Visual Studio solution, these were added using the 'Add existing items' option in Solution Explorer. There has now been an update to the fonts and I'd like to replace the original files with the new ones.

How do I replace these existing items in my solution? Is it as easy as hitting 'Add existing items' again and Visual Studio will overwrite the files, or do I have to do something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a local workspace just replace the files with the new ones in the disk and you will see them in pending changes available for checkin.

If you are using a remote workspace (this is the case if all the files in the workspace are read only) you have to [check out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181395(v=vs.120).aspx) the files first, replace the files with the new ones and then you can check the changes in.
Bear in mind that binary files should be checked out exclusively to avoid other users from modifying the files, otherwise, in case of conflicts (two users editing simultaneously) a merge will probably not be possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can just override the files in the files system. If the name of the file is the same, visual studio will use the new ones. If the file names are different you should you should remove the old ones by just marking them in solution explorer and pressing delete. Then add the new ones by using Add existing items.